# Detect when CK Editor Styles menu is opened?

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

Is there any way to get an event when the Styles Menu in CK editor is opened?

It creates an iFame in the page, and I need to inject a class name into the body tag of that iFrame when it opens....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find a nice way to do this, (events, callbacks, any kind of API in CK) but found a way that suits our needs (uses underscore to wrap a CK function).

Its a bit hacky, but works....

```
    CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( event ) {

          //Expose a class on the styles menu so we can scope the styles and target items that are in the menu
          var Styles = event.editor.ui.instances.Styles;
          Styles.onOpen = _.wrap(Styles.onOpen, function(onOpen) { 

            //Trigger the original onOpen method
            _.bind(onOpen, Styles)();

            //Now find the iFrame and inject a class to the body
            var $iframe = $(".cke iframe");

            if($iframe) {
              var addClass=function() {
                $iframe.contents().find('body').addClass('slide styles-menu');
              }

              if ($iframe.contents().find('body').children().length==0) {
                $iframe.one('load', addClass);
              } else {
                addClass();
              }

            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from a javascript outside the iFrame. You would have to integrate a custom script into the CK editor iFrame.

This is the rule with iFrames, you can't bind events within the iFrame document. the same way it isn't possible from within the iFrame to bind events in the parent document

Comment: I'm not trying to bind to an event within the iFrame itself, I was looking to see if CK triggers an events when it opens the iFrame.  I just need to know when CK has created this iFrame, and then I need run something like this    $(".cke_panel_frame").contents().find("body").addClass("myClass")